# Accents/special characters (e.g., ñ) in verbose_name or help_text ?

Tags: django, django-models, python-unicode

How do I use letters with accent marks or special characters like ñ in verbose_name or help_text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

include this in the head of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and then use this:

```
u'áéíóú'
```

Comment: what's the different between # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  and #encoding= utf-8 ?

Thanks

Comment: in pep 263 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ say is the same thing but editors recognize and can automatic put it in the file the first: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- not the second

Comment: @Asinox it doesn't matter as long as `the first or second line must match the regular expression "coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)"`

Answer (score 0):

i did it:

```
import os, sys
#encoding= utf-8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@diegueus9 has the right answer for using raw Unicode characters in the source file. Use whatever characters you like as long as you declare the encoding as per the instructions in [PEP263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). However, for using just a few special characters you may find this easier: declare the string as Unicode with the `u` [prefix](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) and use the character's code point. The following are equivalent ways of writing "ñ":

```
help_text=u'\xF1 \u00F1 \U000000F1'
```

When it comes to actually finding the code point for a character...that's a little harder. Windows has the useful [Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) utility. [gucharmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gucharmap) is similar. The [charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) at unicode.org provide alphabet-specific PDFs you can search through. Anyone know an easier way?